# Dynamic SwiftUI Color to UIColor

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm trying to convert a `Color` to `UIColor`. Unfortunately, when the SwiftUI color is dynamic (different value for light & dark) the UIColor created is not.

Here is some code example to illustrate the issue:

```swift
let lightTraits = UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .light)
let darkTraits = UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .dark)

let uiColor = UIColor(dynamicProvider: {
    $0.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? .red : .yellow
})
uiColor.resolvedColor(with: lightTraits).hexadecimalRepresentation // #FFFF00 (== .yellow: OK)
uiColor.resolvedColor(with: darkTraits).hexadecimalRepresentation // #FF0000 (== .red: OK)

let color = Color(uiColor: uiColor)
let invalidColor = UIColor(color)
invalidColor.resolvedColor(with: lightTraits).hexadecimalRepresentation // #FFFF00 ( == .yellow: OK)
invalidColor.resolvedColor(with: darkTraits).hexadecimalRepresentation // #FFFF00 (.yellow ??)


extension UIColor {
    var hexadecimalRepresentation: String? {
    
        var r: CGFloat = 0
        var g: CGFloat = 0
        var b: CGFloat = 0
        var a: CGFloat = 0

        getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        return String(format: "#%02lX%02lX%02lX", lroundf(Float(r) * 255), lroundf(Float(g) * 255), lroundf(Float(b) * 255))
    }
}
```

I believe `UIColor(_ color: Color)` is only reading the color for one color scheme...

Comment: Did you tried with only UIColor not CGColor as these last ine as some limitations (« The color object in this property doesn’t adapt automatically to Dark Mode changes.») cf [CGColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621954-cgcolor)

Comment: Hi @PtitXav, thanks for having a look. I remove the `cgColor` from the sample code to avoid the confusion. The issue is the same. I was only using it to get the color hexadecimal value, but I can to it directly using [getRed(_:green:blue:alpha:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621919-getred) !

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: the reason why this happens is that `uiColor.resolvedColor(with: darkTraits)` doesn't apply an "environment" to the `SwiftUI.Color` when evaluating.

You can get the `cgColor` values from a `SwiftUI.Color` for a certain `colorScheme` like this:
[Side note: iOS 17+!]

```
var env = EnvironmentValues()
env.colorScheme = .dark // or .light
let resolved = color.resolve(in: env)
print(resolved.cgColor.components)
```

So ideally you will get the color components from the `SwiftUI.Color` before converting it to `UIColor`. OR you could always convert a `UIColor` back to `SwiftUI.Color`. I tested it with multiple layers of forth and back conversion. You can use those values to get back to a hex representation.

As to why this doesn't work as expected, here's my guess.

1. A `SwiftUI.Color` is a `View`. It's not a "color" in the sense as you'd usually think of it. It's a "SwiftUI view which should be drawn filled with a color".
2. SwiftUI's architecture approach. It's explicitly built declarative. A view instance says: "This is my view structure". Which in turn means that a `SwiftUI.View` is not a visible view. It's a declaration of the structure of something that should get drawn.
3. This has a consequence: You are not intended to read values from a view. Architecturally, an instance of a `SwiftUI` view only means something when provided with environment and state.

Putting your problem into that context: We take a `SwiftUI.Color`, which is a `SwiftUI.View`, which is a definition of structure, which needs an environment and a state to mean something. And we put it into a `UIColor` and inspect/evaluate it outside of that environment and state context. What does that even mean?

We try to simulate an environment via `uiColor.resolvedColor(with: darkTraits)`, but apparently UIColor doesn't translate that to an environment.

This leads us to the solution above: we take a `SwiftUI.Color` and a resolve it by applying an environment with a dark color scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw `resolve(in:)` function you mentioned, but unfortunately it's no good for me, because I need iOS 16. In fact what I'm trying to achieve is a bit different from the TS question, but stumbles into this same problem. What I'm trying to do is to make `Color` conforming to `Codable` by encoding light and dark variants as hexes and then decoding them back. Decoding works good, but encoding doesn't, because it's seemingly impossible to extract the proper dark color from `Color` which in its turn based on UIColor and dynamic provider - you always get the light variant.

Comment: Another approach that would have worked is to create dynamic `Color` directly, skipping `UIColor` and dynamic provider. The reason I think it would work is because the TS code works perfectly fine when you have the dynamic `Color` that's not `UIColor`-based (e.g. `Color.red` or the one from the assets). But unfortunately `Color` doesn't have such initializer either.

Comment: If iOS 17 is not an option, I would suggest to move away from the approach to pass around `Color` instances in the first place. (The reason being that with SwiftUIs architecture you're not supposed to read the values out from a view.) Create your own data structure to hold one set of rgba values for each color scheme. Make that structure `Codable` and pass it around. Only when you really get to displaying the color, use `UIColor(dynamicProvider:)` to create a `UIColor` and from that a `Color`.